# X button to close next privileges and next badges is misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, privileges

[image: pic]

As you can see in the picture, the X button is overlapping on the other text.
This is the same for the next badge popup.

An easy fix would be to raise it and move it to the right a bit.

Comment: Yup, seems that the new side-bar has got some side-effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We pushed a fix and this should be all better now.